# Does it take the same amount of time, it takes for a system to get to a low-entropy (fluctuation) state from equilibrium, to go in the other way?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

Let a system be in a state of fluctuation - a state of low-entropy at $t_0\;.$

Then before and after a sufficiently large but finite time-interval, the system would again be at equilibrium.

As the number of particles $N$ gets larger and larger, probability of fluctuation becomes lesser and lesser.

Eventually the system takes huge amount of time to go back to a large fluctuation state from equilibrium - a high-entropic state.

However, once the system reaches a lower entropy state or fluctuation after a large amount of time $T$ from higher entropic state, would the system take the same huge amount of time $T$ to go back to the higher entropic state from the large-fluctuation state?

Comment: Two comments:
- as N gets larger, only the fractional fluctuations decrease, the absolute fluctuations still diverge. So to say "probability of fluctuation becomes less" is a bit vague, if not incorrect.
- Also could you elaborate what you mean by a "state", a "fluctuation state" and "equilibrium". E.g. equilibrium is defined by it's microscopic fluctuations, so I'm not quite sure what your question is.

Comment: @Numrok: You meant to say in equilibrium, there can be fluctuations?

Comment: yes, in thermodynamics, equilibrium or any "state" is a **macroscopic** property of the system. This means that the exact microscopic details can fluctuate, but the average properties are described by things like pressure, temperature etc.

Comment: @Numrok: I thought the equilibrium is the largest entropic state.

Comment: it is, but entropy is also a macroscopic property. In fact entropy is *defined* through the possible microscopic configurations.

Comment: Entropy is a macroscopic quantity-agreed. But fluctuations??? Could you elaborate these in answer ?

Comment: sorry, I don't really *understand* your question (due to the reasons I wrote in the commets). So I don't feel in a position to answer it.
About entropy again: The value of the entropy does not fluctuate in equilibrium, but the system does. This is because entropy is defined through the probability distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(statistical_thermodynamics)#Gibbs_entropy_formula)

Comment: Could we talk in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35059/discussion-between-numrok-and-user36790).